# Heatmap or other two variable histogram option?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe with two columns, the first one can have an integer from 0-15, the other one can have an integer from 0-10.

The df has approximately 10,000 rows.

I want to plot some sort of grid, (15x10) that can visually represent how many instances of each combination I have throughout the dataframe, ideally displaying the actual number on every grid cell.

I have tried both Seaborn and Matplotlib.

In Seaborn I tried a `jointplot` which almost did it but I can't get it to show an actual 15x10 grid. I also tried a `heatmap` but it gave me an error (see below) and I wasn't able to find anything on it.

I also tried plotting some sort of 3D histogram.

Finally I tried pivoting the data but Pandas calculates the numbers as values instead of treating them as "buckets".

Not sure where to go from here.

```
*heatmap error: "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"
```

```
sns.heatmap(x='pressure_bucket', y='rate_bucket', data=df)
```

The closest to what I want is something like this, ideally with the actual numbers in each cell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTXeU.jpg

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `plt.imshow` to display a heat map,

```
# get the counts in form of a dataframe indexed by (c1,c2)
counts = df.groupby(['c1'])['c2'].value_counts().rename('value').reset_index()

# pivot to c1 as index, c2 as columns
counts = counts.pivot(index='c1', columns='c2', values='value')

# after reading your question carefully, there's another step
# fill all missing value in c1
counts.reindex(range(16))

# fill all missing value in c2
counts = counts.reindex(range(10), axis=1)

# fill all missing values with 0
counts = counts.fillna(0)

# imshow
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.imshow(counts, cmap='hot')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()

# sns would give a color bar legend
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sns.heatmap(counts, cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

Output (random entries)

[image]

Output sns:

[image]

Comment: Hey Quang first of all thank you for your answer, I feel that I'm a lot closer than I was!

However I'm still struggling with this graph, when I show "count" it shows all 0 and when I display the graphs they show very different to yours.

Please check out this image with some screenshots of where I'm at, thanks again!

https://imgur.com/a/jcpp3BU

Comment: Looks like you didn't do `counts = counts.pivot(index='c1', columns='c2', values='value')`. But still it doesn't seem right. can you print the head: `df[['pressure_bucket', 'rate_bucket']].head(20)` and see if the values are what you expect?

Comment: Yeah the head and tail of the dataframe show reasonable data, within the range that I was expecting. Still not sure why the heatmap won't display.

Thanks again

https://imgur.com/a/i7JBEDF

Comment: @adrian I just double check, you forgot the second line of the answer. I dropped that line and get the same pictures as you did.

Comment: You're absolutely right Quang, totally forgot that, works like a charm now, thank you!

https://imgur.com/a/bNuBEiT

Comment: If it works, please consider upvote and accept the answer. Thanks